# Omitting a using statement causes error even for a fully qualified reference

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

The following works fine in VS 2019:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HCA
<p>! @HCA.HttpContext.Session.GetString("x")</p>
```

However, if I omit the `using` statement:

```
@inject  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HCA
<p>! @HCA.HttpContext.Session.GetString("x")</p>
```

I get:

> Error  CS1061  'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'GetString' and no accessible extension method 'GetString' accepting a first argument of type 'ISession' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the latter case, Intellisense shows that `Session` is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession`. In the first case it is just shown as `ISession` but when I traced it, the fully qualified name is also `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession`.

Why is `GetString` missing when the using statement is not there?

Comment: Because [GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.getstring?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_SessionExtensions_GetString_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_ISession_System_String_) is extension method under namespace "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) says:

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax. ... *Extension methods are only in scope when you explicitly import the namespace into your source code with a using directive.*